# How do I reformat an HDD to remove all partitions and erase all data?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have acquired an SSD which I have performed a clean Windows 8.1 install upon it.  Works great.  It is the first in the BIOS boot order to load and it is the drive connected to my first SATA port via AHCI.

My HDD (which once held Windows for me; what the SSD replaces as the OS holder) has been backed up of all files I wish to keep, so the issue of losing files does not factor into my question.  I want to use this drive in tandem with the new SSD to hold all media and temporary files created by Windows (set in the environment variables, natch) and the programs installed on it.

However, there's a bunch of partitions on it from the previous Windows installation and any kind of exploration into the Disk Management tool does not outwardly show a feature to completely obliterate everything on a drive (including the partitions).  Google has only turned up sites about erasing everything to donate a drive but doesn't go into detail if the options and procedures outlined erases all partitions and the containers themselves.  The sites I found also speak about re-installing Windows, which is not my aim here.

**How do I completely format an HDD to erase everything including partitions back to a completely empty state with zero multiple partitions?**  I wish to use the NTFS file system and have a large allocation unit size since this will hold large media files more so than small temporary text files.  The drive is 2 TB.

(I heard about [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) but it does not explicitly say if it wipes out partitions as well.  I am getting conflicting and personally confusing (at least to me) information about DBAN and partitions as [this website](http://ask-leo.com/does_dban_really_erase_everything.html) talks about.)

**ANSWER:** Use the command utility **DISKPART**.  As @chue-x explained and linked from [here](https://superuser.com/a/777282/430509) (and I have confirmed by doing it):

Type cmd at the metro start screen.  Right-click the Command Prompt program that pops up in the upper right search.  Select "Run as Administrator".

`DISKPART`

`list disk`

(note the number of the disk you want to erase all partitions on, mine was 1.)

`select disk 1`

`clean`

Comment: You can use diskpart - see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/777281/how-do-i-delete-all-partitions-on-usb-in-windows-7), but instead of selecting USB disk you select your SSD.

Comment: @chue-x You mean select my HDD?

Comment: Sorry, I meant for you to select whichever drive you want to erase.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  Would never have known about that cmd utility with google alone.  I am editing my initial question to reflect

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your question, you should post a self-answer instead.